# Wrong current slider value on pageload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to show the current value of a jquery slider, this works, but only if I move the slider once. On initalization it is showing this: `"[object Object] seconds"`

This is my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var intSeconds = 10;
     var refreshId;

     $("#container").load("stats.php");
     function sTimeout()
     {
          // Saving the timeout
          refreshId = setTimeout(function() {
             $("#container").load('stats.php');
             sTimeout();
         }, intSeconds *1000);
     }

     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

     // The slider
     $("#ui-slider").slider({
         min : 5, // minimum value
         max : 45, // Maximum value
         step : 5,
         value : intSeconds, // Copy current  value
         change: function(event, ui) {
             $( "#amount" ).val(  ui.value + " seconds"  );
             clearTimeout(refreshId); // clear it
             intSeconds = ui.value; // Update value
             sTimeout();  // Restart it

         }
     });
            $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) + " seconds" );
});
```

What do I have to do to show the correct value on pageload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element name seems wrong. Should be ui-slider

```
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#ui-slider" ).slider( "value" ) + " seconds" );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f2AWC/51/)